# Tag several EC2 instances and output their public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an Ami image at AWS, very often I need to create several instances of this AMI through the web.
Please advise, if there is the possibility to tag each instance and output or get a log with their public IPs.

For example, tag:

- Name: Server 1
- Name: Server 2
- Name: Server 3

Public IP:

- 8.8.8.8
- 10.0.0.1
- 12.0.0.1

I know, that it's possible to do it via terraforming. But I find the possibility to arrange this via a web browser or some other tool.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can click through the AWS web console and manually tag instances and manually extract their IPs. And you obviously can create e.g. a python boto script to do the same.

Comment: Are you asking how to _automate_ this process, or how to do it in the AWS Management Console? Please Edit your question to add details of exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make a bat file, which is running aws cli.
It creates several instances and tagging them by datestamp, after this I can get their IPs.

````
set yyyy=%date:~10,4%
set mm=%date:~4,2%
set dd=%date:~7,2%

SET todayDate=%dd%-%mm%-%yyyy% NewServer
echo %todayDate%

REM aws ec2 run-instances --image-id your_ami --count %count% --security-group-ids your_sg --instance-type t2.micro --key-name wkey --tag-specifications ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=webserver,Value=%todayDate%}] --output text

REM aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:webserver,Values=%todayDate%" --query "Reservations[].Instances[].PublicIpAddress" --output text
pause```
````